# Фамилия, имя, отчество

Tags: лексика, ономастика

В каком порядке правильно называть имя человека: сначала фамилию, а потом имя и отчество или наоборот?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В правильной русской речи, когда говорится о живом человеке, следует указывать сначала имя и отчество (или сокращенные инициалы), а затем фамилию. О мертвом - наоборот.
Это действительно для большинств языком. Исключение составляет японский язык, где всегда первой называется фамилия человека.

Comment: Что за странная идея делить на живых и мертвых?  
Я японском никогда такого не было. Всегда сначала идет имя.   
Вы с венгерским не спутали?

Comment: Согласен с @behemothus.

Answer (score 3):

Имя, Отчество, Фамилия.
Обратный порядок применяется при создании списков и в документах.

Comment: Только что заполняла список трудов по форме. пришлось переставлять инициалы в конец (после фамилий). Мне, конечно, все равно. Только не запомню никак, как правильно.

Comment: Неужели руками переставлять?
Вообще-то на это есть программы...

Comment: А что за программа? Если у меня в Excel в одной ячейке написаны авторы, название, выходные данные - что, программа выделит именно инициалы? Впрочем, проблема того не стоит. Это всего лишь годовой отчет, а я не такой уж плодовитый автор.

Comment: Да запросто. Надо лишь чуть-чуть уметь программировать...
А если авторы постоянные, то и этого не надо. Включайте автозамену - и вперед.

Comment: А, я уж думала, есть готовая программа. Вообще-то раньше автор у меня был один - я сама. В последнее время примазались :-)) 
Шучу, это я примазалась к экологам, у них все время много авторов.

Comment: Есть и готовые, только они под конкретные форматы.

Answer (score 1):

В официальных документах (по крайней мере списках) как раз всегда называют сначала фамилию.